# mysql: simple question on insert

Tags: mysql

I've got a simple question. Supose a table with 100 rows, and AUTO_INCREMENT id. Is there a way to make inserted rows have id's e.g. starting from 1000 (1000, 1001, 1002 ...)

thank you in advance!

PS: please don't advise `set insert_id` as it's necessary to do it, each time before insert

Answer (score 5):

[To start with an AUTO_INCREMENT value other than 1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html), you can set that value with CREATE TABLE or ALTER TABLE, like this:

mysql> ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 100;